# Neo4j Server not Loading: Logback.xml files not Found

Tags: logging, neo4j

I am attempting to connect a small neo4j db to Linkurious, a front end web interface, on a Mac Lion with homebrewed neo4j. The graph was originally working fine, and was accessible from the webser, but in the process of connecting it to Linkurious, something went wriong.

When I try to start neo4j, the server now hangs, and I get the following output:

```
Starting Neo4j Server...19:31:30,507 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
19:31:30,507 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
19:31:30,508 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml]
19:31:30,536 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@33d6f122 - URL [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
19:31:30,632 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
19:31:30,646 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
19:31:30,650 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
19:31:30,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
19:31:30,737 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
19:31:30,737 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
19:31:30,740 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [custom-logback.xml]
19:31:30,742 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@647109c4 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

WARNING: not changing user
process [2350]... waiting for server to be ready...... OK.
Go to http://localhost:7475/webadmin/ for administration interface.
```

The localhost:7475 then proceeds to hang up. I *think* that this is a problem with the path, so I appended NEO4J_HOME to the neo4j file, like here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/NMVHoflUrHo/warnQUInGCgJ (Bhargava's solution).

Nonetheless, the problem persists. Thoughts? I have no idea what the log files do and why they are needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about this logback, you could exclude its libraries. In maven you can do this as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
19:31:30,740 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [custom-logback.xml]
```

indicates that the file custom-logback.xml could not be found.

Comment: Was it supposed to be somewhere? In the java or the neo4j home?